# SQL query help: How can i get the column value from other table?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

```
mysql> describe posts;
    +-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | user_id     | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | title       | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | body        | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | created     | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | modified    | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | category_id | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | tags        | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    +-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

    mysql> describe users;
    +----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | username | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
    | password | char(40)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | group_id | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | created  | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | modified | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    +----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I'm trying to select column id,title from posts table and username from users table where posts.user_id = users.id.

If i select user_id from posts i will get only the integer value.
But i want to get the equivalent varchar value from users table.

It would be a joining sql query.
How can i do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should do the trick

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, u.UserName 
FROM posts p 
INNER JOIN users u ON p.user_id = u.id
```

or

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, u.UserName    
FROM posts p,users u
WHERE p.user_id = u.id
```

or

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, (select u.UserName FROM users u WHERE p.user_id = u.id)
FROM posts p
```

In order of preference

Answer (score 1):

You indeed need to use a join *(most likely an [`inner join`](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Inner_join), here)* between your two tables :

```
select posts.id, posts.title, users.username
from posts
    inner join users on users.id = posts.user_id
```

With this, for each post, you'll get the corresponding user's informations -- and you can add whatever field you want from `users` to the `select` part of the query.

Comment: I don't want posts.* but posts.id,posts.title .But is it possible to get the same result without join keyword ?

Comment: I've edited my post to show how you can get only the fields you want ;; about getting the same result without the join keyword, I suppose you can *(using `from users, posts`, and putting the join-condition in the `where` clause)*, but I don't see why you would not want the `join` keyword, as you are doing a join.

Comment: I'm talking about manual join/inner join without using keywords. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
 SELECT Posts.ID, Posts.Title, Users.UserName 
 FROM Posts INNER JOIN Users ON Posts.User_ID = Users.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select posts.id, title, username
from posts join users
  on posts.user_id = users.id
```

If the column name is ambiguous (e.g., id), you can prefix it with the table name, as shown above.

Comment: Thank you. But is it possible to get the same result without join keyword ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible but it may not be portable to database servers outside MySQL. See Kevin Burton's response below. But I'm curious -- why do you wish to avoid JOIN?